# Sed deleting exact pattern in variable from file

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I've watched many solutions on this site but none of them have helped me solve my problem.
I got a file containing

```
aaa
bbbb
bb
ddddd
dd
ccccc
ccc
```

I've tried to delete an exact line with `sed -i /$1/d ./.resources`
where $1 is user input. when I fill in bb it is suppose to delete only `bb` and not all matching patterns like `bbbb`. I've tried using `\<\>` for exact pattern like `sed -i /\<$1\>/d ./.resources` but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta match only those lines that have the pattern exactly in between the beginning and end of the line by using the ^ and $ operator:
So for your example the code would be:

```
sed -i /^${1}$/d ./.resources
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell sed that the pattern should be matched within this limits:

- Start of the line: ^
- End of the line:   $

So, this will work:

```
set -- dd

sed '/^${1}$/d' ./.resources
```